# why the color is overwrite by the last one?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to draw three line with different colors.But them are in the same color which is the last color.
There is my problem code I think:

```
function initObject() {
        var lineLenth = 10;
        geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        var xMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0xdd5246, opacity:0.2});
        var yMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0xfac942, opacity:0.2});
        var zMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0x149b5a, opacity:0.2});
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-lineLenth, 0, 0));
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(lineLenth, 0, 0));
        var xLine = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, xMat);
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, lineLenth, 0));
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, -lineLenth, 0));
        var yLine = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, yMat);
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, lineLenth));
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -lineLenth));
        var zLine = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, zMat);
        scene.add(xLine);
        scene.add(yLine);
        scene.add(zLine);
    }
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You operate on the same geometry object. You are adding all the vertices to the same geometry. And you're binding materials to the same geometry. This effectively discards previous bindings (first xMat and then yMat) and only keeps the latest binding (zMat).

I recommend splitting your three lines into separate geometries.

```
    // X line: 
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var xMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0xdd5246, opacity:0.2});
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-lineLenth, 0, 0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(lineLenth, 0, 0));
    var xLine = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, xMat);
    scene.add(xLine);

    // Y line:
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var yMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:0xfac942, opacity:0.2});
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, lineLenth, 0));
    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, -lineLenth, 0));
    var yLine = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, yMat);
    scene.add(yLine);

    // Z line: ... you get the point
```